# Having errors when change publish setting to Flash Player8

Tags: flash

I have Flash application that publish with this settings Action Script 2.0 and Flash Player6
but I have ExternalInterface.call and I should upgrade Flash Player setting to Flash Player8
but when I change it Then export the application it have some compilation errors

```
Like:
Scene=Scene 1, layer=Action Layer, frame=1, Line 18 ')' or ',' expected
For:
iconClicked ("drag piece " add whichPiece);
And

Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 16, frame=22, Line 10    ')' or ',' expected
For:
_root.gotoAndPlay("puzzle" add puzznumber);
```

P.S
I do not write the Action Scripts, I just want to expand some features that need ExternalInterface.call

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the only type of issues you have just follow compiles messages and fix the code by  changing of `add` to `+`

Comment: I change add to + and all errors gone....but it still doesn't work correctly !Is there any thing that I should change when change publish setting?